# How print return value in debug - return (WS_BankStatementResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonReplacedString, WS_BankStatementResponse.class);

Tags: apex, json, debug

```
 public static WS_BankStatementResponse parse(String json){
    String jsonReplacedString = json.replace('"date":', '"startDate":');
    System.debug('String Replaced : '+jsonReplacedString);
    return (WS_BankStatementResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonReplacedString, WS_BankStatementResponse.class);
    System.debug('Deserialized : '+); // I want to print in debug
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to print the debug after return statement which will be an unreachable statement.

Please write it above the return statement and check.

OR

You can write your debug statement before return as something like this `System.debug('response after deserialize--'+(WS_BankStatementResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonReplacedString, WS_BankStatementResponse.class));`

so that you can know what's it returning without getting unreachable statement error.

Comment: I want to check value after deserialized

Comment: I have edited the answer. please check

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the response before writing the print statement. This is a compile time error you can see.
Do it as:

```
public static WS_BankStatementResponse parse(String json){
    String jsonReplacedString = json.replace('"date":', '"startDate":');
    System.debug('String Replaced : '+jsonReplacedString);
    WS_BankStatementResponse response = (WS_BankStatementResponse) System.JSON.deserialize(jsonReplacedString, WS_BankStatementResponse.class);
    System.debug('Deserialized : '+ response); // I want to print in debug
    return response;
}
```

Comment: Variable does not exist: response

Comment: response is defined in the line after 1st System.debug statement!